# DB User password policy in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I need to implement password policy (e.g. password expiry, password length etc) in PostgreSQL for DB users. Is there any default configuration in PostgreSQL or I need to implement some 3PP module?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/passwordcheck.html